# Speeding up a matrix computation using parallel processing in C++?

Tags: c++, matrix, parallel-processing, multiplication

I'm trying to compute the following:

Y = Y0 - ( Un.(A*Y0) + Vn.(Y0*Z) )*dt

in the fastest/most efficient manner possible where Y0, Un, Vn, A, and Z are matrices dimensioned on the order of 300 X 300, "." is the matrix dot product, and "*" represents matrix multiplication.

My questions are:

1. Is computing the computationally independent sub-matrices A2 = A*Y0 and Z2 = Y0*Z, then Un2 = Un.*A2 and Vn2 = Vn.*Z2, in parallel faster than computing them serially, such that Y = Y0 - (Un2 + Vn2)*dt? If so, what is a good example of how this parallel computation would be done?
2. Is there some other better/recommended approach (e.g., using ATLAS)?

The language is C++ and this is to be run on a Linux or Windows platform with multi-core (at least dual) processors. I'm currently using BOOST uBLAS as the BLAS package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is very small. You should try using something like Eigen (or as you mentioned ATLAS). I prefer Eigen since it is fast to use.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) should be a quick and easy way of seeing if the parallel route would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @genpfault, on my experiments running several loops I'm  using OpenMP and it is very useful and easier to use!  Here is a link of [chryswoods' blog](http://chryswoods.com/beginning_openmp/basics), OpenMPs basics and it is one of the easiest tutorials I have seen.

Answer (score 0):

I got ~3GFLOPS when trying to multiply similar matrices with boost ublas.  Implementing a cache aware matrix multiplication got me to ~12GFLOPS. Parallelising the cache-aware multiplication with OpenMP got me to ~30GFLOPS (4 cores, 2 threads/core)

So first of all, you should ensure that you are using a cache-aware matrix multiplication algorithm (or cache oblivious one if you like to make it fancy).  Then you can parallelise, but you want to make your parallelism as coarse grained as possible, else Amdahl's law will hit you.

A good rule of thumb is to pick a unit of work that takes at least 1s to execute, and parallelise that.  Here a matrix multiplication only takes a few milliseconds, so I would definitely pick something bigger.  E.g., instead of trying to parallelise a single calculation of Y, you could calculate several batches of them in parallel.